# Wrong count when summarizing dataframe with ddply

Tags: r, plyr

In my dataset I have a continuous variable `mag` from which I derived a categorial variable `mag.cat` which has four categories: 1 for the values between 0 and 1 for `mag`, 2 for the values between 1 and 2 for `mag`, 3 for the values between 2 and 3 for `mag` & 4 for the values above 3 for `mag`. A subset of the data looks like this:

```
   location mag depth mag.cat
1     Assen 1.8   1.0       2
2 Hooghalen 2.5   1.5       3
3 Purmerend 0.7   1.2       1
4     Emmen 2.2   3.0       3
5 Geelbroek 3.6   3.0       4
6   Eleveld 2.7   3.0       3
```

I want to summarize this dataframe into a new one with just one row for each location.

I did this with:

```
df.new <- ddply(df, .(location), summarise, n.tot = as.numeric(length(location)), 
                gem.mag = round(mean(mag),1), 
                n.1 = as.numeric(length(location[mag == 1])),
                n.2 = as.numeric(length(location[mag == 2])),
                n.3 = as.numeric(length(location[mag == 3])),
                n.4 = as.numeric(length(location[mag == 4]))
                )
```

The n.1, n.2, n.3 & n.4 variables are supposed to contain the counts for each category for each location. The sum of these variables should logically be equal to `n.tot`, but they aren't. This can be seen in the head of the new dataframe:

```
      location  n.tot gem.mag n.1 n.2 n.3 n.4
1   Achterdiep      5     1.1   2   0   0   0
2      Alkmaar      4     3.2   0   0   1   0
3       Altena      1     1.3   0   0   0   0
4 Amelanderwad      2     1.8   0   0   0   0
5         Amen      6     1.1   0   0   0   0
6     Amerbrug      1     0.9   0   0   0   0
```

I expected something like:

```
      location  n.tot gem.mag n.1 n.2 n.3 n.4
1   Achterdiep      5     1.1   2   2   0   1
2      Alkmaar      4     3.2   0   3   1   0
3       Altena      1     1.3   0   1   0   0
4 Amelanderwad      2     1.8   0   1   1   0
5         Amen      6     1.1   3   2   0   1
6     Amerbrug      1     0.9   1   0   0   0
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: is it maybe supposed to be: n.1 = as.numeric(length(location[mag.cat == 1])), etc?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand you, but why do you get the length of `mag` and not `mag.cat` when calculating `n.x`. `mag` still contains decimal point values, doesn't it?

Comment: ...also, I'm not sure why you feel that `as.numeric` is necessary here.

Comment: @Rguy @Mark Arghh, I now see my error. Using `mag.cat` gives the desired results :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not:

```
res <- xtabs( ~ location + mag.cat, data=df)
res
```

If you want totals as a column, then `cbind(tot.n= rowSums(res), res)`.

Means of mag: `with(df, tapply(mag, location, mean))`

Everything:

```
 cbind( gem.mag= with(df, tapply(mag, location, mean)),
        tot.n= rowSums(res), 
        res)
```

I suppose the answer is not complete without a plyr version:

```
 require(plyr)
 df.new <- ddply(df, .(location), summarise, n.tot = as.numeric(length(location)), 
                gem.mag = round(mean(mag),1), 
                n.1 = sum(mag.cat==1),
                n.2 = sum(mag.cat==2),
                n.3 = sum(mag.cat==3),
                n.4 = sum(mag.cat==4)
                )
> df.new
   location n.tot gem.mag n.1 n.2 n.3 n.4
1     Assen     1     1.8   0   1   0   0
2   Eleveld     1     2.7   0   0   1   0
3     Emmen     1     2.2   0   0   1   0
4 Geelbroek     1     3.6   0   0   0   1
5 Hooghalen     1     2.5   0   0   1   0
6 Purmerend     1     0.7   1   0   0   0
```